# Empty result of query in PHP , but when I run an SQL query from PHPMyAdmin, it works

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Empty result of query in PHP (wordpress), but when I run an SQL query from PHPMyAdmin, it works !
And here is part of code, which returns empty array

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 
$from = $_POST['amount'];
$to = $_POST['amount1'];

$query = "SELECT  post_content
FROM `wp_postmeta`
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'product_price'
AND meta_value > '$from'
AND meta_value < '$to'";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);;
var_dump($results);  // empty array
?>
```

Anyone can explain my the problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you check if your post fields contain valid values? I would suggest to echo this exact query and see what happens if you paste it in mysql.

Comment: In which file you are using above code ?

Comment: echo `mysql_error` for your query ? If I'm not mistaken in wordpress you could do something like `$wpdb->print_error();`

Comment: Can you provide us with sample input to the script? Try turning on error reporting for PHP, and capturing the MySQL error. One little note - this may just be a test script, but get in the habit of always sanitizing your input. Do you put $from and $to inside quotes in phpmyadmin? If they're floats, then they should not really be inside quotes.

Comment: Yes, $_POST fields aren't empty... I have no ideas, why result of this query is an empty array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure `$from` and `$to` have numeric values.

And then just remove the single quotes from the SQL query.

Comment: This is wrong, the good solution is with prepared statements or at least the $wpdb->prepare(). You cannot NEVER but NEVER trust your inputs. Validate the data always.

Comment: Sure, you should validate them first. My assumption was the problem was the comparison with a string (instead of a number).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for this is that the input to the clauses regarding the meta_value column are being treated as strings. You need to treat them as numerics.

Take a look at the 'query_posts' function in Wordpress.

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query'=> array(
    array(
      'key' => 'product_price',
      'compare' => '>',
      'value' => $from,
      'type' => 'numeric'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'product_price',
      'compare' => '<',
      'value' => $to,
      'type' => 'numeric'
    )
  )
  'posts_per_page' => 100
) );

query_posts( $args );
```

Alternatively, have your inputs treated as numerics, not strings. Remove the single quotes around them in your original query.

```
global $wpdb; 
$from = $_POST['amount'];
$to = $_POST['amount1'];

$query = "SELECT  post_content
FROM `wp_postmeta`
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'product_price'
AND meta_value > $from
AND meta_value < $to";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
var_dump($results);
```

I still highly recommend you get in the habit of sanitizing your input.

An added benefit of the first solution, is that the query_posts function will automatically sanitize your input, based on the input type provided.

References:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/query-posts-using-meta-compare-where-meta-value-is-smaller-or-greater-or-equ

Comment: Why would you need to cast the numbers as floats?

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the meta_value field is a string, not a numeric. I'm not 100% versed with the structure of Wordpress tables. Surely, when using a numeric operator with a string, the string would need to be cast as a numeric?

Comment: But why would you do it INSIDE the SQL string? It's awkward (and unsafe)

Comment: I've just checked, and a string can be compared against a numeric, without having to cast it. Updated my answer. Also, while I agree casting in the query like that (while, in my opinion useful sometimes, in other circumstances) is awkward, can you explain how it is unsafe? Cheers (purely out of interest, not questioning your statement).

Comment: Having $to and $from variables directly into the $sql without any sanitising is prone to SQL injection attacks. 

Imagine if $from had something like "0; DELETE * FROM users; SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE 1 "

Comment: Yes, that I understand, hence why I stated 'I still highly recommend you get in the habit of sanitizing your input.', and also mentioned input sanitation in the comment to the original post. The query posted was simply a modified copy of the original one, no sanitation added. The question was not on the topic of safe queries, and as such I won't provide an answer so off topic, but I'll at least mention sanitation. I thought you meant the function CAST itself was unsafe - a case of crossed wires, I believe.

Comment: IMHO, better than simply stating it, it's to write a valid example.

Answer (score 0):

I really care about security and all answers no one was concerned about it so I am adding the best solution for this because you should NEVER trust your inputs you need always to validate it.

Below should be a good working solution.

Also you should read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results).

```
<?php
global $wpdb; 
$from = $_POST['amount'];
$to = $_POST['amount1'];

$query = "SELECT  post_content
FROM `wp_postmeta`
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'product_price'
AND meta_value > %d
AND meta_value < %d";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $from, $to));
var_dump($results); 
?>
```